# How to find dependencies of gtk

Tags: gtk, licensing

We have gtk 2.16.6 in our library, and there are a lot of other libraries that appear to be dependencies (pango 1.24.0, glib 2.20), but I'm looking for a readme file or something to show the lawyers that states that it uses those libraries.  The reason we are doing this is for our product that we are distributing, we need to identify and state what licenses we are using.  The worst license will prevail for something that uses other licenses/libraries.  This is the only way I can see getting around the lawyer asking us what exactly gtk is explicitly doing with all of the other libraries.

I tried searching online but I don't see info on dependencies for gtk.  I opened the library, and there are some readme files that say something about the release of a version of glib causing an error, but it doesn't really say it's a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the best method to finding the real libraries linked would be to use `ldd` on each shared object built. Gio and GdkPixbuf do have a few libraries that can be loaded at runtime which would be a bit trickier to track down. A look at what various distributions list as deps would be helpful or possibly just finding the paths libraries look for external modules in and going back to `ldd` for them.